# Beagle bone black - no boot text

Tags: debugging, beagleboneblack

I'm working with a beaglebone black with an image based off the [base debian image for these boards](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images).

When I plug this into a monitor via the onboard HDMI and boot it, I get the linux penguine (Tux) in the top left corner and not much else until it gets to a command prompt.

I've checked the kernel parameters and `quiet` is not set.  Does anyone with experience of this particular build know what they have done to hide all of the debug text (kernel startup, output from initramfs, output from systemd).

Comment: quick search reveals this directive for hiding boot messages ... perhaps you have something like that ... `console=tty12`

Comment: That's not in the params. But thinking about it, there's a lot of instructions on the internet for attaching a serial console. I wonder if I need a parameter like this to tell it to use the screen instead of serial.

Comment: try adding `console=tty1` (i think that is the name of the first console) ... also, try pressing ctrl-alt-F1 during boot ............. there could also be a verbosity setting somewhere

Comment: also found a loglevel directive .... `loglevel=4`

Comment: Interestingly seeting the `console=tty1` has persuaded the kernel to write to the console.  But everything else (initramfs, systemd) is still hidden.